# Parenscript name conflicts with uncommonweb (UCW)

Tags: common-lisp, parenscript

Many name conflicts arises when I use-package :parenscript in UCW . Parenscript doesn't work if I keep old ones (also, parenscript misbehaves with direct parenscript:ps call) and if I import new ones, UCW seems to be broken. Is there any way in common lisp to use packages with conflicting names side by side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *also, parenscript misbehaves with direct parenscript:ps call*

I guess this is because if you don't *use* the package, symbols such as `parenscript:@` won't be imported, and so:

```
* (ps:ps (@ a b))

"at(a, b);"
```

But if you do:

```
* (ps:ps (ps:@ a b))

"a.b;"
```

> Is there any way in common lisp to use packages with conflicting names side by side ?

If you need both `foo:a` and `bar:a`, then you cannot just write `a` and let the interpreter find out what you mean. So you have to qualify at least one them.
Do you need to use the parenscript package and import non-conflicting symbols ones from UCW ? Do you need to `shadow-import` other ones? Without more details, it is hard to say what is the best thing to do here. 
In case you need it, see [Programming in the Large: Packages and Symbols](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/programming-in-the-large-packages-and-symbols.html) (*Practical Common Lisp*, P. Seibel).